# Passing directory contents as a single line to an executable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cat, get-childitem

I have a binary executable that takes a list of file paths as arguments, e.g.,

> C:\Tool.exe C:\Files\File1.txt C:\Files\File2.txt

I would like to call this tool from Powershell. The question is, how can I get the output of get-childitem all on one line?

If I run:

> ls C:\Files\*.txt | select FullName

I get one path per line. How can I concatenate the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0 you can use the -join operator:

```
(ls C:\Files\*.txt | %{ $_.FullName }) -join ' '
```

In PowerShell 1.0 you can set `$OFS`, which is used to combine a sequence of items when they are used as a string:

```
$ofs = ' '
"$(ls C:\Files\*.txt | %{ $_.FullName })"
```

Comment: +1. Even though I'd use `-join` or `[string]::join` which is probably less side-effect-prone. with `$OFS` I tend to overlook it when reading code.

Comment: @Johannes - Agreed, just trying to give some options.